# VBA Resizing 2 Identical Images to the same size (width and height)

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010, excel-2007

**Step 1)** Open Up Excel, Copy "stackoverflow's logo into sheet: https://blog.stackoverflow.com/wp-content/uploads/stackoverflow-logo-300.png

**Step 2)** Copy and paste that logo twice

**Step 3)** Resize one of the logos manually to some ridiculous size: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ON9kz.png

Now how can that nasty logo be resized via vba to the same size as original logo

I tried the following macro (yes I tried using With / End With):

```
Sub sds()
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Picture 2")).Width = ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Picture 1")).Width
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Picture 2")).Height = ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Picture 1")).Height
End Sub
```

It skewers it and it ends up looking like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QrwNH.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a property `.LockAspectRatio = msoTrue`setted per default for shapes which contains images. This causes your described behavior.

To avoid this you could switch this to `msoFalse`, then change `.Height` and `.Width` and the switch it to `msoTrue` again:

```
Sub picture_size()
   ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Picture 2")).LockAspectRatio = msoFalse

   ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Picture 2")).Width = ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Picture 1")).Width
   ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Picture 2")).Height = ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Picture 1")).Height

   ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Picture 2")).LockAspectRatio = msoTrue
End Sub
```

But if the goal is only to restore the original size, then:

```
Sub picture_100Percent()
   ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Picture 2")).ScaleHeight 1, msoTrue
End Sub
```